# Embedding of a torsion-free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $R$ be any commutative ring with $1$, and let $M$ be any finitely generated torsion-free $R$-module. Can we embed $M$ into a free $R$-module of finite rank?

As we know that it can be embedded if $R$ is a domain. Since we can then take the tensor product of $M$ with $K$ (the quotient field of $R$) and find suitable basis so that we can embed. But I don’t know whether it is true for any commutative ring or not?

Comment: What definition are you using for torsion-freeness for a non-domain?

Comment: m is said to be torsion if rm = 0 for some non zero r.

Comment: got it..it means that R must be domain.