# Embedding of a torsion free module into a free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with the unit element (not necessarily being an integral domain) and $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. The following proposition is well-known:

> If $A$ is an integral domain and $M$ is torsion-free, then there is an injective $A$-module morphism $M\to A^{n}$ with some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$.

My question is: Is the above proposition still true even if we do not assume $A$ is an integral domain?

The essentially same question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2871971)
but OP there gave too strong definition for "torsion-freeness" when $A$ is not an integral domain. I think if we use the following definitions, then the problem is not so immediate as in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2871971):

- We say $a\in A$ is *a zero-divisor* if there is a non-zero $b\in A$ such that $ab=0$.
- We say $a\in A$ is *regular* if $a$ is not a zero-divisor.
- We define *the torsion submodule* $T(M)$ of $M$ by
  $$
  T(M) := \{x\in M\mid\text{there is a regular $a\in A$ such that $ax=0$}\}.
  $$
- We say $M$ is *torsion-free* if $T(M)=0$.

Comment: It is worth noting that $T(M)$ is the kernel of $M \to \mathrm{reg}(A)^{-1} M = M \otimes_A \mathrm{reg}(A)^{-1} A$, where $\mathrm{reg}(A)$ is the submonoid of regular elements, which means that $\mathrm{reg}(A)^{-1} A = T (A)$ is the total ring of fractions of $A$. If we assume $T(M)=0$, therefore $M$ embeds into a finitely generated $T(A)$-module. This already basically finishes the proof in the case of an integral domain, since then $T(A)$ is a field. It also then works if $A$ is reduced with finitely many prime ideals, since then $T(A)$ is a  finite direct product of fields.

Comment: If $ A$ is a boolean ring, then $\mathrm{reg}(A)=\{1\}$ and hence *every* $A$-module is torsionfree. I highly doubt that every f.g. $A$-module embeds into $A^n$.

Comment: Yes. So let's look an non-noetherian (i.e. infinite) boolean rings.

Comment: Yes this looks promising. Perhaps A/I for every ideal I which is not f.g. works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the ring to be $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and $M=A/(x)$. Then $M$ is torsion free in your definition (since the only regular elements in the ring are units).
If $M\subset A^n$ for some. $n$, one easily checks that $M$ is contained in $(x,y)^n\subset A^n$. But, the annihilator of $(x,y)^n$ is $(x,y)$, while the annihilator of $M$ is $(x)$. This contradiction shows that $M$ is not contained in a free module.

Comment: Thank you for a nice and simple counterexample!